# TFS workspace error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, workspace

When I try to do a local mapping from TFS, I get the following error,

> The working folder --- is already in use by the workspace ---;User on computer ---

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you add more context?

Comment: Just remap the workspace to a different local folder.

Comment: @Mkram Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: I had use the tfs sidekick tool to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the referenced workspace is no longer in use, you can delete it with TF.exe.

`tf workspace /delete [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl] workspacename[;workspaceowner] [/login:username,[password]]`

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/workspace-command?view=vsts

You can also use a tool like Attrice TFS Sidekicks to find and delete it.

Otherwise, listen to what the error says and map the workspace in a different folder.

Comment: I can't delete the workspace, because it is still in use.
Apparently TFS has assigned the workspace to another user

Comment: @Mkram "TFS" hasn't done anything. A user created that workspace. You'll have to choose a different folder.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and could not install sidekick because I'm running VS 2k17.

I was unable to delete the workspace because it kept telling me it could not find the workspace. It was giving me the error even though I could clearly see the workspace in the workspaces list using:

```
 tf workspaces /computer:* /owner:*
```

When I copied the exact values from the listing above and tried deleting the workspace with the syntax below I got the resulting error:

```
 tf workspace /delete myWorkSpaceName;Bob Smith
 TF14061:  The workspace myWorkSpaceName;Bob Smith does not exist.
```

The solution for me was to ask for xml format:

```
tf workspaces /computer:* /owner:* /format:xml
```

Now the resulting list of workspaces included a lot more information including workspace owner aliases not show in the simple listing. One of them was a long name with a guid and the account email for the owner. This finally worked for me:

```
tf workspace /delete myWorkSpaceName;aabe3ec12-1254-4956-b1ee-3fb26506931e\bsmith@myDomain.onmicrosoft.com
```

It asked for a confirmation and finally deleted my orphaned workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue in Visual Studio 2017 too, and this is how the error message looks like:

[image: Microsoft Visual Studio: Error: The working folder C:\… is already in use by the workspace … on computer ….]

I did a lot of reading in vain, so this is what finally helped:

- In Visual Studio, under <kbd>View</kbd>→<kbd>Other Windows</kbd>→<kbd>Source Control Explorer</kbd>, the <kbd>Workspace</kbd> dropdown said there were no workspaces, but when I tried to add a new one, it yielded the above error.
- Since I had to TFS in PATH (i.e. no `TF` in cmd), I typed `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017` in the Start menu and ran this CLI with administrator privileges.
- First I wanted a list of my pending changes, so I knew what to save locally: `TF status /r /user:%USER_NAME%`.
- Then I checked which workspaces were associated with my user by typing `TF workspaces /collection:"http://%TFS_SERVER_NAME%:8080/tfs/%COLLECTION_NAME%" /owner:%USER_NAME%`.
- Now I deleted my workspace mappings by typing `TF workspace /delete %WORKSPACE_NAME%;%USER_NAME%` and confirming the potential loss of uncommitted changes.
- Finally, I re-started Visual Studio and was able to create a clean new workspace (with the previous settings), mapping server to local paths. Alternatively, you can do it via <kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>Source Control</kbd>→<kbd>Advanced</kbd>→<kbd>Open from Server…</kbd>.

Comment: Another hint: check the Windows _Credential Manager_ for a possible user account to the TFS server.